# How to use web workers with svelte and esbuild?

Tags: typescript, web, svelte, web-worker, esbuild

I'm following this tutorial on how to use web worker in `svelte` but I'm getting an error
https://publish.obsidian.md/kometenstaub/50-Programming/Esbuild+web+worker

Svelte file Codeblock where I use worker

```js
  import Worker from 'src/timerWorker'
  const worker = Worker();
  worker.postMessage(['hello world']);
```

`timerWorker.ts`

```js
self.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

In `esbuild` config I specify plugins

```js
    plugins: [
      esbuildSvelte({
        compilerOptions:{ css: true },
        preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
      }),
      inlineWorkerPlugin(),
    ],
```

The error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My worker file was named in wrong format.

`Supported file extensions for the worker are .worker.js, .worker.ts, .worker.jsx, .worker.tsx.` Source: https://github.com/mitschabaude/esbuild-plugin-inline-worker#esbuild-plugin-inline-worker